# TRIAC gate resistor keeps getting burned

Tags: triac

**R85** in the following circuit keeps getting burned out when the photo-triac is turned on.  It may last for a few minutes before burning out.  It is a smallish 1/10 W resistor, while **R83** is in DIP package.

I am confused about what's causing **R85** to exceed its power rating.  **AC_HOT** is 220 VAC.  The load is an inductive load (an incline motor, rated at 15W).

Is there anything in the following circuit that does not make sense? Any pointers are appreciated.

[image]

[BT137-600E datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BT137-600E.pdf)

[PC1S3063NTZF datasheet](http://images.ihscontent.net/vipimages/VipMasterIC/IC/SHRP/SHRPS03175/SHRPS03175-1.pdf)

Comment: Where is the load connected?

Comment: The load is across LUG10 and AC_NEUT.  I have edited the post.  Thanks. :-)

Comment: If you include links to the datasheets for the components you're using, it makes it a lot easier on people who might be interested in answering your question.

Comment: How is the gate current supposed to be limited? Aren't you going to get  10ma * 220V = 0.2W through it?

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks.  I will include the links next time. :)

Comment: If that resistor is burning up, you must be forcing something on the order of 100 mA RMS through it, which is also close to the absolute maximum for the optocoupler. Was this circuit originally designed to handle inductive loads at 220V? Keep in mind that with reactive loads, the zero crossings of the current do not align with the zero crossings of the voltage, and this puts a lot  of stress on this type of circuit, which is often rated "for resistive loads only."

Comment: Dave is quite correct. For inrush current avoidance (when the magnetic material of the inductive core saturates) you need to switch the circuit initially when the 220VAC is near a peak NOT as it passes thru zero.

Comment: We have also tried [Q6008RH4](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/240/E4AlternistorTriac-61114.pdf), which is a High-Comm  triac, while BT137 is an ordinary 4Q triac.  With Q6008RH4, the resistor does not get burned or not as easily (we have not seen it burned yet).  I think there is something fundamentally wrong with the circuit.  I am not sure about the values of the resistors and how much current flows through them.

Comment: @DaveTweed Do you mean that excessive voltage spikes when the gate of the TRIAC is being turned on and off is causing the resistor to burn up?  I tried hooking up a scope but the waveform of 220V AC gets clipped...  I also tried to measure the current flowing through **R85** but my DMM has trouble measuring the short pulses.  I did put the scope across **R85** and saw a max of 0.7V.  If my calculation is correct, that does not exceed the resistor's power rating.  How/Where do I measure/observe the **stress** on **R85**?  Thanks.

Comment: @pjc50 Could you elaborate a bit more about the gate current?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia article about TRIACs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC)? It has a lot of detail that I think is relevant to your situation, particularly the part about [commutating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC#Commutating_dv.2Fdt_and_di.2Fdt). I think you're getting very large, very narrow spikes of current through the gate resistor each time the main triac tries to turn off at a current zero-crossing.

Comment: @DaveTweed I think that's it!  That's why 3Q TRIACs do not fry the resistor.  I guess for the circuit to work with 4Q TRIACs, a proper snubber RC should be added.  Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet for the triac says the average gate power is .5 watts. You need a resistor rated for at least that. Also, If we look at the [Triac wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC#Commutating_dv.2Fdt_and_di.2Fdt) it discusses that 3Q triacs are designed to operate heavily inductive loads. This would explain it functioning better. Normal TRIACs or 4Q triacs have problems due to high voltage and current angles when they turn off at zero crossing. They experience a voltage spike which can turn them back on again. Commutations (▲v/▲t) can be improved with the use of snubber networks. They are designed to provide at need to help balance the circuit. With the introduction of 3Q triacs this problem was avoided. If shopping for a device like this you can simply search for "Snubberless Triacs" which is what they are often called.

Answer (score 0):

There is **nothing** wrong with your schematic that I can see. The gate resistor should only dissipate a few milliwatts average, since it stops conducting once the triac turns on. (10mA for a couple microseconds every 1/2 cycle).

What do you mean "DIP" package for R83- I would expect that to burn up first if it had a similar rating.

I wonder if you have the triac wired incorrectly, or if one of the parts is defective.

Make sure the triac wiring is correct. The view of the package is from the **top**.

[image]

If the triac gate is shorted to the MT1 or the triac is damaged such that it never triggers, you will see something like what you have observed, however R82 will see a lot more power dissipation.

If you still need help, posting a photo of the circuit would not hurt.